# Find a counterexample that the derived set of union of a set and its derived set is not the derived set of A.

Tags: general-topology

If $A'$ is the set of all limit points of $A$,does it hold that $(A\cup A')'=A'$?

I proved the first inclusion but can not find counterexample for the opposite.

Thank you!

Comment: It does hold. To get started take $x \notin A'$. What can you say?

Comment: Note that $A\cup A' = \overline{A}$ is the closure of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x\in A'$, then every open neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $A$ distinct from $x$. Thus every open neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $A\cup A'$ distinct from $x$, showing $x\in (A\cup A')'$.

If $x\in (A\cup A')'$, every open neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $A\cup A'$ distinct from $x$. Given an open neighborhood, it contains a distinct point from either $A$ or $A'$. I claim there's an argument (which I leave to you) that, either way, it contains a distinct point from $A$, showing $x\in A'$.